# Use data in plugin outside the SCIPsolve call

Tags: scip

I would like to share data between a plugin and my main function (this is, use it outside the call to the `SCIPsolve` function). For example, a branching rule sets a certain int variable to 1 and then, after the optimization is done I can go and check wether the variable was changes or not.

I thought I could accomplish this by using the plugin data (e.g. `SCIP_BranchruleData`) but it can't be accessed from outside the plugin's source file.

How can I do it?
I will appreciate any help.
Rodolfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is to add a getter function to the branchrule which you implement in `branch_xyc.c` and prototype in `branch_xyz.h`. Then your code needs to include the header file and you can access the fields in the branchdata.

See also the documentation of [branch_allfullstrong.cpp](http://scip.zib.de/doc/html_devel/branch__allfullstrong_8c_source.php#l00351) where an external function is defined and you can see how to get the branchdata and branchrule when passing just a `SCIP` pointer.